# Distortion along edges only in viewer

Tags: objects, 3d-view, interface

I couldn't figure out how to quite word this so sorry if it has been asked before, but I would like help with a weird glitch I am experiencing.

So I've been working on this shape (I hope to mirror later on) which I crafted out of a cylinder. I want to get into good habits, so I worked hard to get all the vertices and edges just right, no simply overlapping anything. I double-checked for duplicates and I do not THINK there are any but I could be wrong. When I move around the scene I see these weird distortions.

[image]
See the mangled line at edge of screen.

But When I double check my render everything seems fine.
[image]

When I unhide the other object the effect gets worse, but still it doesn't affect my render. I have checked as best I can for duplicates, but I am afraid the problem might be in some obscure viewport setting, which is more of a maze for me.  It doesn't help that I don't know how to word this issue.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe the clipping settings in the N panel > View?

Comment: This was it.  I had set clip start to its lowest possible setting (.0000001 or something like that).  Thank you so much.  I feel dumb for forgetting I did that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the *Clipping* settings in the *N panel > View*.

Comment: Thank you so much!